# After mac os sierra update facing scrolling issue with Java applications like Intellij

Tags: swing, intellij-idea, java-8, jscrollpane, macos-sierra

After the recent update, Mac os Sierra, to my Macbook pro, I'm facing scrolling issues with all Java applications like Intellij IDEA community edition.

The scrolling in the editor panes are extremely fast. The unit of 
scroll increments seem to be large.

Intellij IDEA Version is 2016.2.3.
Java version is Java 8 Update 10.1.

I see the same behavior even in the "System Preference" -> "Java" -> "Advanced" tab .

Comment: You need to install JDK from JetBrains.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158500), likely caused [by the JDK](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158500#comment=27-1619333):

> It looks like JDK issue and is reproducible with a simple scrollable JList.
>   Sierra generates much more events than El Captain.
>   These events contain values ~0.1 instead of expected ~1.
>   But Java converts these small number to 1 anyway.

Edit: see also this OpenJDK bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166591

Edit2: as described in the other answer, JetBrains have fixed their custom JDK. You can [download it here](http://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/download_file?file_path=jbsdk8u112b403_osx_x64.tar.gz) and follow [these instructions](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/05/intellij-idea-14-1-4-eap-141-1192-is-available/) to make IntelliJ use this JDK instead (select the option labeled `...` to choose a custom location).

Comment: Thanks Bastien for sharing the issue id. Eagerly waiting for the fix from Intellij.

Comment: After download you have to place extracted jdk folder to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines. Otherwise it will not appear on Switch IDE boot JDK. I saw this in AndroidStudio.

Comment: @SattarHummatli the last option, labeled `...`, allows you to choose an installation located in any directory.

Comment: @BastienJansen, May be there is such option in Intellij, but in Android Studio not option labled `...`. It only shows options from `JavaVitulaMachines` folder.

Comment: @SattarHummatli I don't have a /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines folder... I tried creating it and extracting the jdk folder there, but it still doesn't show up in Android Studio in the options for "Switch IDE boot JDK". Any ideas?

Comment: @magritte, maybe your default JDK has located in other location. Let's try to find that location. In Android Studio open , File->ProjectStructure->SDK Location->JDK Location. Find what is your JDK's root folder path. Then add your new JDK beside it, after try again

Comment: @SattarHummatli thanks Sattar, that helped i realised i was being silly and looking under (user)/Library rather than the root /Library folder! Works now :-)

Answer (score 10):

You need to install JDK from JetBrains as it includes fix for this issue.

Link to [JDK](http://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/download_file?file_path=jbsdk8u112b403_osx_x64.tar.gz):

Unpack it somewhere, press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, paste "`Switch IDE Boot JDK`" and point to unpacked directory.

Link to [instructions](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/05/intellij-idea-14-1-4-eap-141-1192-is-available/) from JetBrains.

**UPD:** JetBrains **fixed** this issue in latest build. See [link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2016.3+EAP).

Comment: The JDK "fix" makes the scrolling in JetBrains products _jerkily_ instead of insanely fast. Sadly, this is a problem of Apple product which needs third-parties to fix.